# Why must IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() and GetEnumerator() be implemented?

Tags: c#, iterator, ienumerable, ienumerator

Working on implementing the `IEnumerable` interface.
I actually found two methods that need to be implemented:

```
public IEnumerator<Item> GetEnumerator()
System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
```

Not sure why I need to implement these two methods (which look quite similar). Could anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Part of the answer is "for historical reasons".

The `IEnumerable` interface has been around since .NET 1.1, whereas generics (and thus `IEnumerable<T>`) were added in .NET 2.  `IEnumerable<T>` extends `IEnumerable`, which was a sensible decision because it allows you to use an `IEnumerable<T>` in code that was already written to take an `IEnumerable`.

But that means that to implement `IEnumerable<T>` (which includes the `IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()` method) you also have to implement `IEnumerable` (which includes the `IEnumerator GetEnumerator()` method).

As Servy noted, it's not that big a deal, because you can just do this:

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }
```

where the non-explicit implementation `GetEnumerator` is the one whose return type is `IEnumerator<T>`.

Answer (score 11):

`IEnumerable<T>` extends `IEnumerable`, so you need to provide both a generic and non-generic version of the method.

A common solution is to have the non-generic solution simply call the generic solution, since `IEnumerator<T>` also extends `IEnumerator`.